# How to restrict user password OAuth token within role in WSO2IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have a basic question. Usually we configure user activities & permissions (basically Scopes) based on specific roles. If we have two roles like Manager and Employee, user in Manager role can have scope -   'Create Employee', 'Delete Employee'.

A user in Employee role will not have this right. He will have only 'View Employee' option. I have created two roles in WSO2 Identity Server as Manager and Employee. How can I assure Scopes such as - 'Create Employee', 'Delete Employee' are  assigned to Manager. Employee role will have only 'View  Employee' scope permitted ? Can I do this mapping in WSO2IS ?

Also when I try to call Auth2 token with grant Type as user password,

```
curl -k -X POST https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -H 'Authorization: Basic <base64encoded(client_id:client_secret)>' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=<scopes>'
```

We need to mention scope as shown above. How will I make sure user with Employee group will not get token with 'Create Employee', 'Delete Employee' scopes? When the user in Employee role request for token user can mention any Scope. Is there a restriction we can enforce, so that  user will not ask for OAuth token with Scope, for which the user don't have rights?

This is basic design question? This question thrown to me during one of my design discussion.

Comment: Could you please mention the version of WSO2 Identity Server that you are trying this, then I can point you to the documentations relevant to that version.

Comment: thansk for the reponse , We are currently using  WSO2IS v 5.5.0 .

Answer (score 1):

We can use Role based scope validator to do restrict OAuth2 scopes with user roles.

First, you have to register the scopes with their respective roles [1].

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "profile", "displayName": "profile", "description": "get all profile information", "bindings": ["role1", "role2"]}' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/oauth2/v1.0/scopes"
```

Then you have to enable the role-based scope validator inside the OAuth2/OIDC config section of the service provider.

After that, the requested scopes are allowed only if the user is having the respective role for that scope. Other token requests will be rejected.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/apidocs/OAuth2-scope-endpoint/#!/operations#ScopeManagement#registerScope